# Video Streaming and Broadcasting using WebRTC

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, live-streaming

I am very new to Real Time Protocols and I had some questions about how WebRTC works and how I can implement it. I am trying to create a one to many livestream like facebook or periscope, where one user broadcasts and other users join and stream the video. I am using Swift from my client end.

My questions are:

1. How do I broadcast a video using WebRTC
2. Is there an SDK for WebRTC in Swift/iOS

I know the questions are very vague but a guidance to the right direction would be great because I am not sure where to start

Comment: Any particular reason why you feel you must use WebRTC?  There are some very distinctive tradeoffs with this set of technologies, so it's important for you to make the right decisions up front for your use case.

Comment: What are the drawbacks of WebRTC? Is building it in RTMP better? @Brad

Comment: There's little reason for RTMP these days, but it's hard to help you without knowing more details about your specific situation.  That's why I was asking why you felt the need to use WebRTC.  WebRTC is a great set of technologies when low latency matters more than anything else.  That is, if you don't care about quality at all and only want to make sure someone can have a video chat, WebRTC is solid.  WebRTC can also be used for content delivery but there are a ton of operational challenges with that... be prepared to spend mountains of cash.  What *specifically* are you trying to do?

Comment: I am creating a livestreaming/broadcasting app similar to facebook except people have to be in a small distance radius around you. So basically it is one person broadcasting and many pulling the stream. @Brad

Comment: How small of a distance?  What are the people using for watching?  Are they all on the same network by chance?  If you're only using native apps and have tight control over the situation, you might get away with streaming this over the local network, eliminating the infrastructure costs.  What are the latency requirements?

Comment: The app lets you pick your distance, it has a minimum of 10 m and a max of 50m. Users are probably not gonna be on the same network so that won't work. I want the latency to be pretty low around 3-4 seconds

Comment: Sounds like WebRTC is solid for your use case.  While you can get 3-4 second latency with most any non-segmented streaming tech (i.e. *not* DASH, *not* HLS), you'll have a relatively small number of people around and existing WebRTC gateway servers are sufficient for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to use backend servers for that.

If you plan on broadcasting to multiple users directly from your mobile app then stop...

You need to connect your mobile app to a backend media server which then can be used to broadcast the video to a larger audience.

There are several commercial and open source alternatives that enable you to do that. I'd check [Red5Pro](https://red5pro.com/), [Wowza](https://www.wowza.com/), [SwitchRTC](http://switchrtc.com/), [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/), [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/) and [Kurento](https://www.kurento.org/) for this task.

For the client side, look at [react-native-webrtc](https://github.com/oney/react-native-webrtc)

You can find more tools for WebRTC developers [here](https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-developer-tools-landscape/).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question (2), there's also a SDK for iOS [here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleWebRTC) and a neat get-started-page [here](https://tech.appear.in/2015/05/25/Getting-started-with-WebRTC-on-iOS/) (although 2.5ys old, but I haven't found anything better so far yet)